# How do I add a reference to an assembly that wasn't built with the Silverlight Runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am looking for a possible solution where I can add ShapeMap.dll as a reference, 
but when I try to add the reference I get an error stating:

> You can't add reference to ShapeMap.dll, as it was not build against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight Assemblies"

What do I do now?

Comment: And what is ShapeMap.dll? i.e. are you able to compile it for SL?

Comment: ShapeMap.dll is a library available to render shapes files into Bing !

Comment: No I cant compile it on silverlight, I am not sure how to do it without being able to access source code !

Comment: I don't really understand the problem here. The error message is clear, is it not? Since the assembly is built for the .NET runtime, you cannot add it to a Silverlight application. That's what "can't" means. You cannot do this. Either recompile the assembly for Silverlight, if that is even possible, get a different assembly to do the job, or you're forced to rewrite the required functionality.

Comment: Thanks  Marc Gravell &  Lasse V. Karlsen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Silverlight code may look and smell like good old .NET-backed logic,
 **the runtime for Silverlight is *different* from that supporting regular .NET applications**.
It is useful to think of the Silverlight runtime as a *subset* of the .NET runtime: Silverlight is meant to run in a "sandbox" whereby many the unsafe features such as direct access to the file system are not allowed.

For this reason, one can only add Silverlight assemblies to a Silverlight project.

The error you're getting is therefore as said: the version of ShapeMap.dll you have wasn't build for Silverlight runtime.

There are two ways out of this situation:

- find or build a Silverlight-backed version of the DLL
- somehow refactor the Silverlight application so that it leverages the features of the DLL by way of WebServices (if that makes sense, for the name ShapeMap.dll indicates that this may deal with UI objects which are hard/impossible to deal with remotely)

To get a Silverlight-backed version of the DLL:
First choice: It may just be that you can get the *binary* of the Silverlight version of the assembly where you found the .NET version.
Second choice: it may be that you can get the the *source code* of the [.NET targeting] DLL.
If so you can *try* -and I stress "TRY"- to make a Silverlight assembly out of it.  The problem may be that the source code uses .NET-only idioms/API calls and you'll then need to convert these; several just .NET-to-SL "gotchas" can easily be converted, others are absolute roadblocks (eg. direct access to the file system, registry etc.), although, it may be possible to merely comment-out the offending sections of the code, if, somehow the Silverlight was not going to use the underlying features of the DLL.

Now... for sake of full disclosure...
there are a few techniques which allow "fooling" Visual Studio so that .NET assembly be accepted within a SilverLight project. See for example ["Reusing .NET assemblies in Silverlight"](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight).  Beware, however, that while very insightful as to the nature of the .NET and Silverlight runtimes, and possibly useful in some cases,  these techniques are undocumented and, more importantly, depending on the subset of .NET API used by the DLL, may merely allow to get over over the build-time blocking, to fall into various run-time errors (when/if the application makes calls into the DLL to methods which in turn invoke .NET-only methods of the runtime).

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to the source files for that assembly (dll), create a new Silverlight Class Library project and add all the existing source files to your new project. Then attempt to build the project. Depending on the amount of dependencies you may succeed in building a silverlight compatible version of the assembly.

If you don't have the source code, then sorry you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight works in a "subset" of the .net framework, some stuff is organized differently and works not like a regular WPF application (like that everything needs to be async in order to keep the UI responsive). You can see it as a "protected" .net environment, and therefor you may not reference or use non-silverlight dll's.

Like the previous answer states, use the source code and copy paste it into a SL library project, compile, and use that.

Comment: It isn't a strict subset; there is an intersect, but both have unique parts